# My Ubuntu 20.04 running on a virtual box won't boot up after installing a software

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, ubuntu-20.04

So, basically I am running Ubuntu 20.04LTS on my windows laptop.
I use this Ubuntu in a Virtual box and use it mainly for programming. After installing Visual Studio code, Ubuntu froze. So I had to shut down the virtual box and then restart it again. When restarting, Ubuntu stopped at this screen. [black screen error with just underscore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBgFG.jpg) , [specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdcjV.jpg). Note that I have been using this virtual machine since the past 2 weeks without some freezes for a couple of times but never like this. I tried changing Graphics Controller too!

This is my first time posting here, so I apologize in advance if I made any mistakes in posting this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The machine specifications appear to be fine (similar to specifications I use for my own Ubuntu Virtual Machine (VMware).

1. Do you have a backup of the machine?  I assume perhaps not.
2. Close down Virtual Box and all other apps. Restart your host computer. Start Virtual Box.   Does the Ubuntu machine now start?
3. If no, close Virtual Box again, copy (not move) the Ubuntu machine folder to a new folder.  Start Virtual Box, make a NEW machine and point now to the NEW folder for the machine. Does the machine start?  I have used this trick successfully before.
4. If using all the above, you still cannot start the machine, you will need to build a new machine.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I tried 1 and 2... no luck there. Will try 3 an update you on that. Cheers!

Comment: Ended up with 4 :(

Comment: i thought that is what might happen, and so I included that option. You may now wish to acknowledge my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the command below. This worked out for me.

/sbin/vboxconfig

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert but I had the same issue and managed to fix this by reading: https://askubuntu.com/questions/297080/ubuntu-open-to-black-screen-with-blinking-underscore-character-after-release-upg

The steps I used were:

1. Hold the right shift key on boot and navigate to recovery mode.
2. Select the option to create some space on hdd.
3. Select the option to drop into root shell.
4. Uninstall Visual Studio by running `apt purge code` then `apt autoremove`
5. Run `service gdm3 restart` and reboot the machine.

Hope this helps someone!